# Unable to upload Jenkin's generated .iPA to TestFlight or HockeyApp

Tags: jenkins-plugins

Jenkin-ers out there ! Please help me out here .

Use Case : 
I am now on a exercise of Configuring Jenkins to fetch committed code base from my Personnel GIT repo, build and generate the .iPA and later automatically push this build to either TestFlight or HockeyApp.

Things working :
Jenkins would now pull the GIT code base , build the project and generates .iPA and other files.

Things not working :
Fetch the .iPA executable from the desired location and push to TestFlight / HockeyApp. Below are the Console Logs from JENKINS :

```
Results at '/Users/shriharsha/.jenkins/jobs/GITTestFlight/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa' 
[Release-iphoneos] $ ditto -c -k --keepParent -rsrc /Users/shriharsha/.jenkins/jobs/GITTestFlight/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/BarCodeScanner.app.dSYM BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0-dSYM.zip
Uploading to HockeyApp...
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at hockeyapp.HockeyappRecorder.perform(HockeyappRecorder.java:321)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1770)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Build step 'Upload to HockeyApp' marked build as failure
Uploading to testflight
No file to upload was found with paths search criteria: '/Users/shriharsha/.jenkins/jobs/GITTestFlight/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa'
Build step 'Upload to Testflight' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please let me know whats wrong here and looks really strange for me.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you tried manually uploading the .ipa file to testflight using the testflight desktop app? I have tried this and it is not able to process the file for some reason. Perhaps there is a project structure difference or provisioning is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/hockeyapp-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hockeyapp/HockeyappRecorder.java#L321), I would guess that the path to your .ipa file is not correct. Note that this has to be a path relative to your workspace.

Comment: Thanx for your reply Ashtom, but the path set or logged are correct. If you check on the line No 1 , the path reads '/Users/shriharsha/.jenkins/jobs/GITTestFlight/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa' and the same path is logged in "No file to upload was found with paths search criteria :..........." log.

Comment: I feel its able to write the .ipa into a particular folder but not able to read from the same.

Comment: `/Users/shriharsha/.jenkins/jobs/GITTestFlight/workspace/build/Release-iphoneos/‌​BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa` is not a relative path. Correct would be `build/Release-iphoneos/‌​BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa` if `workspace` is your Jenkins workspace. Note the help text for this input field in Jenkins.

Comment: ashtom, i did check on this. Below is the error log :

Comment: Uploading to testflight
No file to upload was found with paths search criteria: 'build/Release-iphoneos/BarCodeScanner-Release-1.0.ipa'
Build step 'Upload to Testflight' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE